Feasibility of Creating a WebGL Build with Unity Transport 2.1+ and Netcode for GameObjects (NGO)
I have developed a multiplayer card game using Netcode for GameObjects (NGO) and planned to deploy the clients via a WebGL build hosted on a web server. However, I am encountering significant difficulties in achieving this.
I am seeking advice on the feasibility of my current project design, and in case it is feasible some guidance on overcoming the issues I’m facing.
What I Have Done So Far:
A. Research and Documentation: I have read various forums and Unity documentation that indicate Unity Transport 2.1+ supports WebGL builds.
B. Conditional Compilation: surround the multiplay sdk code with #if UNITY_SERVER || UNITY_EDITOR Implemented the #if SERVER as Multiplay code simply can’t be exported into Android builds. As discussed in this discussion
C. Minimal Project Structure to isolate the problem:
-Player and Player Manager scripts.
-Network Manager object with NetworkManager comp.
-Server Startup
-MatchmakerClient script - with simply pool rules to ensure functionality.

While I added Transport 2.1 and added Conditional Compilation, I keep encountering errors. Every time I resolve one error, another one appears. The project works locally,. A build NGO test allocation is successful. However, generating a fully functional WebGL build that includes multiplayer functionality has been elusive. I can create a WebGL build without the multiplayer design, but integrating everything has not been successful.
I spend some long nights on this and I wonder if keep banging my head against the wall is the right way to advance…
Precisely my questions are:

Feasibility: Is it feasible to achieve my design goal using Unity Transport 2.1+ and NGO for a WebGL build?

Alternatives: Should I consider setting aside NGO if I aim to stream clients from a web server? What are the risks involved in continuing on this path?

Resources: Are there any tutorials, repositories, or detailed guides that could help me navigate this process effectively?


Any insights, advice, or references to relevant resources would be immensely appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Of course you can. The only difference is you need to select wss (I think eg not udp or tcp)  as your transport.   Im not sure why you had issues, it worked first time for me, the only question i would have is where is your server?

Thanks for the comment. You seem to strongly support the idea, which is good. I don't find though any documentation about it. If I use unity NGO server it is rather a tough struggle to load a webgl build, ie. the conditional compilation. Then I still have some unresolved issues, so far, like CORS and the web-socket lack of connection to the NGO cloud server. The issue is not that I bang my head against the wall... expected during a development, but I find no relevant documentation about it. Can you please share more about the base of this design confirmation?

Id give you the url but my base server is down. Cos well i only really made it to prove i could. So. Tbh the only thing i had to do was set transport to the websockets. Other than that it then worked fine. While its not clear one thing i had you may not from your writing was it was webgl clients not server. Now, i do believe you can achieve server with webgl but i didnt try that. Initially to save the whole type ip or code or whatever i on startup sent the code to a web page and allowed clients to pick it up. I then changed to relay.  But all worked fine.
